# How can I fix 403 error when trying to push to github?

Tags: git, macos, github

I recently got a laptop by a friend, he still had stuff installed like github. I added my credentials to gitconfig, adding username and email, but I didn't change the password because I am unsure how to. I think this is why I am getting this error:

(rizumu is the username of my friend - since I changed the username I am confused why it is addressing me with his username still)

> remote: Permission to hannarosenfeld/brnhrz-cms.git denied to rizumu.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hannarosenfeld/brnhrz-cms.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: _"stuff installed like github"_... do you mean [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 403 error is for invalid authentication, you can try cloning the code again and try using personal access token (instead of password). Below links may help
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Thank you, creating a connection to the access token fixed my issue.